# Moving toplinks to another block in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm trying to move the toplinks to a static block that I created above the header. Currently, I'm only getting the "Log Out" link instead of all of the top links (My Account, My Wishlist, My Cart, and Checkout). How can I get all these links into the static block?

**2columns-right.phtml**

```
<head>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
    </head>
    <body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
        <div class="page">
            <div><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newreference') ?></div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
            <div class="main-container col2-right-layout">
                <div class="main">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                    <div class="col-main">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-right sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_cookie_notice') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**newReference.phtml**

```
<p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
        <div class="quick-access">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
        </div>
```

**local.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <layout>
        <default>
            <reference name="root">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="newreference" as="newreference" translate="label">
                    <label>New Reference</label>
                </block>
            </reference>
            <reference name="newreference">
                <block type="core/template" name="newreferenceblock" template="newreference.phtml">
                    <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
                </block>
            </reference>
        </default>
    </layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <reference name="newreference">
        <block type="core/template" name="newreferenceblock" template="newreference.phtml">
            <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
        </block>
   </reference>
```

change this to

```
<reference name="newreference">
    <block type="core/template" name="newreference" template="newReference.phtml">
        <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: When I do that the block disappears altogether.

Comment: When it disappears try exit; in newReference.phtml and links.phtml? Is it exiting?

Comment: Same result with the "exit;" in the newReference.phtml and links.phtml. When I do that the block disappears altogether.

Comment: which means newReference.php is not being called. As there is a block defined in customer.xml it is showing only login or log out button. Try adding the reference block code in page.xml.

Comment: a. newReference.phtml is being called because I've added code to the page which does functionally display on the website. b. I've added the reference code block to the page.xml and it still does not work. Any more ideas?